# Is it possile to return .NET object from controller to middleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I was working on one of the requirements, where I need to modify result data in middleware (not any MVC Filters due to some other services injected through middleware).

In middleware I was getting data in json format and then deserializing that data then updating that data and finally serializing to JSON and sending it back as a response.

I don't want to serialize data in MVC pipeline so I tried to remove output formator but that didn't work for me and throwing error.

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.Clear();
        });
```

Is there any solution to get the .Net object in the pipeline and modify that object (as we do in MVC filter) and then serialize at last?

Comment: Can you provide a pseudo code of what you want to do? I am a bit confused. Are you trying to modify a returned `ActionResult` (which I think only Action Filter can do since Middleware doesn't have concept of ActionResult), or a Response, or something else?

Comment: And did you check [Result filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

Comment: @LukeVo I used soapcore nuget package to expose my services as SOAP with REST. If I would modify the result in Result filter, it would work for REST requests, since SOAPCORE  separate from mvc pipeline, I don't want to write my business logic in 2 places (for REST request in result filter and for SOAP in middleware).

Comment: I see. Then yeah you will need to use `HttpContext.Items`, or a scoped service.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether it fits your requirements but you can use HttpContext to store some data in the scope of the request. There is a 'Items' key-value collection.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer is good but it would nicer if you can provide some example code :)

Answer (score 3):

Beside the other suggestion to use `Items` of [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0), I want to note that you **can** inject services into Action Filters:

```cs
public class ResultFilter : IActionFilter
{

    // Inject anything you want
    IHostEnvironment env;
    public ResultFilter(IHostEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is OkObjectResult result)
        {
            result.Value = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
            {
                Value = result.Value,
                Environment = this.env.EnvironmentName,
            });
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { }
}
```

Register to DI Builder:

```cs
services.AddScoped<ResultFilter>();
```

Apply to action/controller:

```cs
    [HttpGet, Route("/test"), ServiceFilter(typeof(ResultFilter))]
    public IActionResult ReturnOk()
    {
        return this.Ok(new
        {
            Value = 1,
        });
    }
```

Testing by accessing the URL:

```json
{"Value":{"Value":1},"Environment":"Development"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use DI service with [`Scoped` lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#lifetime-and-registration-options).

> Scoped objects are the same for a given request but differ across each new request.

Service:

```cs
public interface IMyRequestDataService
{
    object? MyData { get; set; }
}

public class MyRequestDataService : IMyRequestDataService
{

    public object? MyData { get; set; }

}
```

Register to DI:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IMyRequestDataService, MyRequestDataService>();
```

Set data in Controller:

```cs
    readonly IMyRequestDataService dataService;
    public TestController(IMyRequestDataService dataService)
    {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("/test-scoped")]
    public IActionResult ReturnObj()
    {
        this.dataService.MyData = new
        {
            Value = 1,
        };

        return this.Ok();
    }
```

Your middleware that consumes it:

```cs
class CustomMiddleware
{
    readonly RequestDelegate next;
    public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    // Add DI Services here
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IMyRequestDataService dataService, IHostEnvironment env)
    {
        await this.next(httpContext);

        // Data should be here
        if (dataService.MyData != null)
        {
            // Do something with it
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new
            {
                Data = dataService.MyData,
                Env = env.EnvironmentName,
            });
        }
    }

}

// Register it:
app.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();

// Make sure it's before the Controller middleware since we wrap it around the next()
// ...

app.MapControllers();
```

Test with the URL:

```json
{"data":{"value":1},"env":"Development"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in HTTP context items.

In controller action:

```cs
Request.HttpContext.Items.Add("SomeKey", data);
```

In middleware:

```cs
object data = httpContext.Items["SomeKey"];
```